# What's is the best way to migrate dovecot imap accounts to office365

Tags: dovecot, imap, microsoft-office-365, exchange-migration

i need migrate some accounts from dovecot imap service (how cpanel setup) to office365.
This accounts should be of diferent licences  businnes and kiosk.
Is this possible?

Any suggestes?

Somebody has experience in this migration type?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provide a method of migrating `IMAP` accounts to Office365.

Effectively you upload a csv file containing the IMAP account information to your office365 account and the office365 servers will then connect to those accounts and pull all the email across.
See [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/What-you-need-to-know-about-migrating-your-IMAP-mailboxes-to-Office-365-3fe19996-29bc-4879-aab9-5a622b2f1481) for full details

Depending on the amount of email you have this process can take sometime, you will also need to leave it in place after you change over your mx records as it isn't "live". Make sure you take note of the limitations mentioned on that page.

Answer (score 0):

1. Backup the current emails saved in Outlook.
2. Create Exchange account and add to Outlook.
3. Import .PST file to the new mailbox and let it upload and sync to
   the new servers.

Comment: Thanks but I have more than 50 accounts and some users can be use thunderbird client . I thinking other way than user per user

Answer (score 0):

You should use the dsync tool supplied by Dovecot.  This will synchronise IMAP accounts in multiple steps, so you can perform an initial sync and then a final sync when you're ready to switch over.

This method can be done from the commandline on your Dovecot server and so automated for all your mailboxes.